# XCODE DEBUG lldb is hiding all variables

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, lldb

I am  trying to debug my code as you can see in FIGURE 1 and I have a breakpoint at line 301, but for some unkown reason xcode is hiding all variables values at this point after I press "Step Over" to jump to line 302 as you can see in FIGURE 2. Someone knows how can I solve this problem?

[image: FIGURE 1]

[image]

Comment: Did you intentionally added an expression "self.beacon" in "Variable View" ? What happened ?

Comment: Since the location of variables can move around as execution proceeds through your code (into registers, back to the stack, etc.) the debug info has to track variable location and report that to the debugger.  Looks like you've hit a bug in the compiler's debug output. where its loses the location of the variables for a little range of your code.  That is certainly a known failure mode.  If you can get a reduced case that reproduces the problem which you can submit in a bug, or if you don't mind submitting your project, please do so at http://bugreporter.apple.com